# Multiple undefined index showing in index.php

Tags: php

I am learning to use php to make dynamic webpages. I created the my site through a tutorial. it works beautifully except the following lines keep coming up on my index.php page:

Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\xampp\htdocs\janewoo_new\index.php on line 6
Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\xampp\htdocs\janewoo_new\index.php on line 8
Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\xampp\htdocs\janewoo_new\index.php on line 10 ...

here are my code on the index.php:

```
<?php

include("includes/header.html");
include("includes/navbar.html");

if($_GET['page']=="traditional_teampage.html"){
include("includes/traditional_teampage.html" );
}else if($_GET['page']=="traditional_mediapage.html"){
include("includes/traditional_mediapage.html");
}else if($_GET['page']=="traditional_faqpage.html"){
include("includes/traditional_faqpage.html");
}else if($_GET['page']=="traditional_casepage.html"){
include("includes/traditional_casepage.html");
}else if(isset($_GET['page'])=="consumer-proposal.html"){
include("includes/consumer-proposal.html");
}else if($_GET['page']=="bankruptcy.html"){
include("includes/bankruptcy.html");
}else if($_GET['page']=="community.html"){
include("includes/community.html");
}else if($_GET['page']=="traditional_contactpage.html"){
include("includes/traditional_contactpage.html");
}else{
include("includes/traditional_home.html");
}

include("includes/footer.html");

?>
```

I put isset() as described in other people's answers but then the buttons all go to the first same page. I am more a designer than a programmer, and I am doing my best to learn php. hope someone can help me. much appreciated.

Comment: My eyes, they're bleeding! Please indent your code ;(

Comment: You need to check `isset($_GET['page'])` everywhere and not just once. Also consider using switch statement instead of so many else ifs.

Comment: Please [Use this instead](http://pastebin.com/EBFQE0fz) and learn from it.

Comment: `}else if(isset($_GET['page'])=="consumer-proposal.html"){` note this line is incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correct the warnings change:

```
if($_GET['page']=="traditional_teampage.html"){
```

to become:

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) and $_GET['page']=="traditional_teampage.html"){
```

---

Also consider a switch/case statement for this kind of structure

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

```
switch((isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : null)
{
  case 'traditional_teampage.html':
  case 'traditional_mediapage.html':
  case 'traditional_faqpage.html':
  case 'traditional_casepage.html':
  case 'consumer-proposal.html':
  case 'bankruptcy.html':
  case 'community.html':
  case 'traditional_contactpage.html':
    include('includes/' . $_GET['page']);
    break;
  default:
    include("includes/traditional_home.html");
    break;
}
```

or even a  simple `in_array()` "whitelist" for your include.

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) and in_array($_GET['page'],array(
  'traditional_teampage.html',
  'traditional_teampage.html',
  'traditional_mediapage.html',
  'traditional_faqpage.html',
  'traditional_casepage.html',
  'consumer-proposal.html',
  'bankruptcy.html',
  'community.html',
  'traditional_contactpage.html'
)))
{
  include('includes/' . $_GET['page']);
}
else
{
  include("includes/traditional_home.html");
}
```

Comment: thanks, Scuzzy, for your help. I put your code into the file but there is an error :Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\janewoo_new\index.php on line 17.      line 17 is   {
  include('includes/' . $_GET['page']);
}
else.          A note: I used your array code.

Comment: Sorry not enough closing brackets, try again, I changed `))` to `)))`

Comment: Scuzzy, you are amazing. I used both of your codes and both work perfectly now. thanks for the links also. I will study them more. I am new to php but I like it very much.

Comment: Neat, please accept this answer for your question _(green tick)_ :)